# Tensorflow: How to obtain the hashtable from a trained model

Tags: tensorflow, hashmap, hashtable

I have trained a LinearClassifier using tensorflow. To handle categorical values, I use a similar approach to [this link](https://github.com/AshutoshDongare/Tensorflow-Wide-Deep-Local-Prediction/blob/master/wide_deep.py) using :

`tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list, 
 tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket`

I also use crossed_columns as in the linkprovided

I can easily get the coefficients *only*. For example, if I want to obtain the weights of the feature 'device':

`model.get_variable_value('linear/linear_model/device/')`

I can also easily map these coefficients to the categorical variable values trained with tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list. However, this is not possible for the  categorical variable values trained with tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket. I can not get how to do the mapping. Since the hash table is done dynamically, I do not know which weight corresponding to which value.

I have looked in several places even digging into the code of the [estimator](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.7/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py)

Any ideas?